Marginal empirical distribution from joint sample
I have a quite 'simple' doubt that would like to clear.
Suppose I have a heiarchical model where data is sampled in the following manner:

Sample $U_i$ from $P_U$
Sample $X_i$ from $P_{X|U_i}$

In other words, depending on the values $U_i$ sample $X_i$ from a different distribution.  The $U$ are i.i.d. but the $X$ are only i.i.d. given each $U_i$.
Let  $\mathcal{U},\mathcal{X}$ be the supports of U and X respectively. I am now interested in estimating the empirical distrbiution of the data. If I were to observe samples of $(U_i,X_i)$ then an estimator for the \underline{joint} empirical distribution is the empirical distribution:
$$F_{U,X}(A)\approx\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n1_{(U_i,X_i)\in A}\quad\quad A\in \mathcal{U}\times\mathcal{X}$$
Suppose I now do not observe the latent variable U. How do I estimate the marginal distribution of X? Is the dependence on U going to cause problems? I know that $F_X(X) = \int F_U(X,U)dU$ but how does this translate in practice?  Is an estimator for the marginal distribution of X simply:
$$F_X(B)\approx\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n1_{(X_i)\in B}\quad\quad B\in \mathcal{X}$$
Am I overcomplicating a simple problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Let's reframe this as simply as possible and see where that leads: "I observe a variable $X.$  How do I estimate its distribution?  Does this estimate depend on other variables I haven't observed?"  I hope the answer is now very clear.

The $U_i$'s are iid, therefore the $X_i$'s also are iid (marginally).
